# 3D Bubble Chart in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am struggling with developing a 3D bubble chart in R plotly. Plotly has a nice tutorial in python, but I have been unable to replicate in R.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(mtcars, x=mpg, y=cyl, z=disp, type='scatter3d', mode='markers',
        marker=list(sizemode='diameter', sizeref=750, size=hp, color=drat, 
                    colorscale = 'Viridis'))
```

Comment: your code works if you remove sizeref=750 from your code

Comment: Thanks @MLavoie. In fact it looks like I don't need these arguments in the 'marker' list. I'll show my code below for future reference.

Comment: and you can still `size=hp/5` to adjust the bubble base size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(mtcars, x=mpg, y=cyl, z=disp, type='scatter3d', mode='markers',
        sizemode='diameter', size=hp, color=drat, colorscale = 'Viridis')
```

[image]