# How to visualize custom 3D bubble charts in PowerBI using R-Code?

Tags: r, rstudio, powerbi, plotly, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm setting up a visualization of  one data set. The visualization should be a 3D-Bubble-Chart, So that every data entry should be represented by one bubble.

I want the 3 axis and size of one bubble to represent 4 different quantitative valuation measures.

```
x-axis: VM1, data range 0-10;
y-axis: VM2, data range 0-20;
z-axis: VM3, data range 0-10;

bubble size: VM4, data range 20.000 - 2.000.000;
```

The bubble color should impose the belonging of the data entry to one of five categories.

```
bubble color: Category, number of categories: 1-5
```

I have already found that the plotly package provides a 3D Bubble Chart, but I have struggled to "recode" it, so my application works.

Can somebody support me and show how I can optimaly set up the code using the plotly 3D-bubble chart package?

The goal is to implement the plotly visualisation in PowerBI.

Comment: here is the link to the plotly 3D plot: https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3D Bubble Chart in R Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361425/3d-bubble-chart-in-r-plotly)

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, since the way to Color the bubbles is different (in the linked post it's a shaded color-way, while I want 5 different Colors for 5 different categories)

Comment: Believe it should work the same, just instead of using a `colorscale`, you pass a vector of colors to the `colors=` argument as shown in this example: https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/#3d-bubble-plot